# Unity not loading after a fresh install of 16.04

Tags: unity, 16.04, compiz

I just installed 16.04 on a new PC and when I log in unity does not load properly. All I can see is some popups flashing on the top right corner. I can go into TTY and when I try to launch unity from there I get these errors.

```
compizconfig - Info: Backend     : gsettings
compizconfig - Info: Integration : true
compizconfig - Info: Profile     : unity
WARN  2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:217 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -- full D-Bus introspection will not be available
WARN  2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.dash.gsettingsscopereader GSettingsScopes.cpp:108 Error fetching protocol metadata for scope: social.scope : Valid key file could not be found in search dirs
ERROR 2016-05-14 18:21:59 unityte <unknown>:0 g_object_set: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
ERROR 2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.launcher.icon.trash TrashLauncherIcon.cpp:66 Could not create file monitor for trash uri: Operation not supported
WARN  2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARN  2016-05-14 18:21:59 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
WARNING: no DISPLAY variable set, setting it to :0
```

I tried various fixes that told me to reset the configs for compiz and reninstall it but those do not work. Moreover when I try to --reinstall unity or ubuntu-desktop it tells me that they can not be downloaded. What should I do? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you tested the iso you downloaded from the Internet to see if the checksum is correct?

Comment: @Elric Good reminder but md5 checksums match.

Comment: What hardware is the new pc?

Comment: @Elric I have a MSI GTX 960 4GB. Hey man thank you for your interest in the question.

Comment: Try `gksudo unity-tweak-tool --reset-unity` from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2141007&page=2), may need to `sudo apt install unity-tweak-tool` before. This is a desktop right? Are using Bumblebee or something to switch video card?

Comment: @Elric Hey man that actually worked thank you so much!